# UWP application syncing Load testing

Tags: uwp, azure-sql-database, load-testing

I have a uwp application and there is a button which calls an api to sync data from/to cloud azure db. How can I perform a load testing?

Comment: you have not provided any code for what you tried and what error you got, your question is too broad.

Comment: I tried recording app traffic with jmeter but nothing was recorded so I have no code. I thought uwp doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load testing of standalone applications is an [oxymoron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) as desktop or mobile application is going to be used by only one person at a time and the number of requests which can be send by this application is limited to the velocity of its user.

So if you need to test the **application** performance - you should stick to [Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-tools?view=vs-2015) and analyze CPU, RAM, Network, Battery usage by the application, check for memory leaks, large objects, slowest functions, etc.

On the other hand you might want to simulate hundreds/thousands of the UWP applications concurrently accessing the backend, to wit test performance of the API endpoint/database - you just need to mimic the relevant API call using one of the load testing tools. Depending on your Visual Studio license you may have [Visual Studio Load Testing Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=vsts) available which is the most obvious choice given integration with other application development lifecycle toolchain. If not - there is a number of [free and open source load testing tools](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use), the majority of them are even capable of recording requests and replaying them with increased number of virtual users.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and sorry for the late reply but I wanted to try things myself first and ask based on a poc. I tried jmeter but I couldn't capture the requests from my uwp app! Ithink maybe it's a port issue. Do you know how to configure a uwp app to use a specific port? 
also I want to have a retention policy for my app since syncing a big volume of data hangs the application. so I need to do it using a volume test right ? do you have any thought about this ? thanks in advance.

Comment: The application configuration can be different, it should either have a separate proxy settings or it can respect the operating system underlying proxy configuration. In case of HTTPS protocol you will also need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your application/operating system. Check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for more information